# How to perform logic in sql statements

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my second (what I would call noobish) sql question, and although I know I should improve my sql knowledge, in this case I have left high and dry by a fellow developer.

Anyway, the problem. I am using mysql 5

I am dealing with a store procedure api. One of the sp's was to return all rows of a table along with some other calculated results from said table.

```
Table: reports
ID|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|col_5
--------------------------------
 x| xxx | xxx | xxx | xxx | xxx
```

I am trying to calculate an index of completion (the previous developer did not add a column for this, and time doesn't allow me to refactor).

So if...

```
col_1 is not null
col_2 is not null
col_3 is null
...
```

The stage would be `2`.

And if...

```
col_1 is not null
col_2 is null <<-- notice the empty field
col_3 is not null
```

The stage would be `1` as there is an empty field.

So the stage increments until there is an empty field.

Now I know I could retrieve all rows and process this information with php but I don't want to veer from the design of the system.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: Should stage be the same as the number of last non-null column?

Comment: @Quassnoi The column names are irrelevant in this case. The incrementing names were made up.

Comment: in your example, should it?

Comment: No as there are other columns which aren't required to calculate the stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with by summing the matches:

```
select ((col_1 is not null) +
        (col_1 is not null and col2 is not null) +
        (col_1 is not null and col2 is not null and col3 is not null) +
        (col_1 is not null and col2 is not null and col3 is not null and col4 is not null) +
        (col_1 is not null and col2 is not null and col3 is not null and col4 is not null and col5 is not null)
       ) as IndexOfCompletion
. . .
```

Comment: Worked first time. My only mistake was a check for `0` rather than `null`. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

```
Select Case
        When col_1 Is Null Then 0
        When col_2 Is Null Then 1
        When col_3 Is Null Then 2
        When col_4 Is Null Then 3
        When col_5 Is Null Then 4
        Else 5
        End
```

Comment: This was the perfect solution for human readable text to my status